# Where to find the source code for the Almquist Shell?

Tags: source, ash

I'm learning the Unix shell command language looking for a repository that contains the source code for the Almquist shell ("ash" / "dash") but I could not find it. Can you help me find the source? I'm looking for the source code to a minimal shell and it seems that the Almquist shell is one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two widely used variants of `ash` nowadays are `dash`, which has a [repository on kernel.org](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/dash/dash.git), and the Busybox `ash`, which has its [own repository](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/).

The [Almquist Shell variants](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/) page lists many variants and provides links to their source code, including [the original post on Usenet](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.sources.unix/msg/2774e7653a8e6274).

Comment: FreeBSD and NetBSD sh's are two other main variants, `dash` started as a fork of NetBSD sh and still regularly pulls changes from FreeBSD or NetBSD shs.

Answer (score 1):

The ash sources do not exist as a downloadable portable entity.

They only seem to exist in BSD specific trees that do not compile elsewhere.

Dash seems to be easy to find. Search for `dash-0.5.8.tar.gz`.

One of the results is: ftp://ftp.tuwien.ac.at/.vhost/www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/postlfs/dash.html