# What is the difference between `ash` and `sh` shell on Linux?

Tags: shell, ash

I am new to a lot of tools on Linux. A quick search did not help, I only got more about `bash` or `sh`, and searching for it somehow leans towards `bash` in the search results. There are quite a few different shell types out there, I have even seen `zsh`, thus I guess they are all forks from `sh`.

There is already a question [What is the difference between using bash and sh to run a script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270966/what-is-the-difference-between-using-bash-and-sh-to-run-a-script) that is similar:

- but I could not find out what the "a" stands for in a shell
- and this question is also not just about running a script, but the shell as such - since I can choose to take `ash` or `sh` for a docker container at hand.

I remember `ash` would be more comfortable though still very slim, and I have forgotten why.

What is the main difference between `ash` and `sh`? size, handling, ...?

Base image was `python:3-alpine`, even the one with the latest tag (2022-07) has both `/bin/ash` and `/bin/sh`. There should be a reason why the two are there in the alpine image that is made to be the most compact of all.
I call it with `docker-compose -f docker-compose-develop.yaml run --rm MY_CONTAINER ash`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Historically, `ash` is the Almquist Shell. [What does it mean to be "sh compatible"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145522/86440) gives its history in the overall context of `sh`-style shells, and [Where to find the source code for the Almquist Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276477/86440) explains where to find it.

Nowadays, on Linux systems providing a shell named `ash`, it’s either `dash` or Busybox `ash`, both of which derive from the Almquist Shell but have significant differences.

On current Linux systems, including in containers, there are three common scenarios:

- `sh` is Bash (in `sh` mode) — this will always be larger and more featureful than `ash`
- `sh` is `dash` (Debian derivatives) — in such systems, installing `ash` will result in a symlink from `ash` to `dash`, so `ash` and `sh` have the same size
- `sh` is Busybox — the specifics will depend on the options used when building Busybox, but by default now Busybox `sh` is `ash`, so `ash` and `sh` have the same size

(On Android, which is also Linux, `sh` is `mksh`, and the same comment applies as for Bash.)

Shells can vary their behaviour depending on how they are invoked, so starting the shell as `ash` or `sh` can result in a different experience. However as far as I can determine, that is not the case for Busybox `sh` when `ash` is the default (as is the case in your container image).

Comment: I will check for a different behaviour over time and come back. I heard that it `ash` was in some way more comfortable. Your answer is helpful since it might also - on top of my general question - depend on the base image. And you might be right that it will not change anything, but that needs to be checked. I will tell, cannot say when.

Comment: It may be more correct to say that `dash` and busybox are based on `ash` as there have been several strands of shells based on the original Almquist shell with years of independent development done on top. IIRC dash was initially based on a port of NetBSD sh to Linux.  You'll find major differences between dash, busybox ash, NetBSD sh, FreeBSD sh all based on ash.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas right, my point is really that on Linux nowadays, if you install `ash` (using the system’s package manager), you’ll get `dash` or Busybox `ash`.

Comment: Ash-based shells can also be built with or without a line editor (which may be what the OP's *comfortable* is about).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, I thought that might be what was going on, but in all the systems I tried, `sh` and `ash` behave the same way (for example in Debian, neither support exploring history using cursor keys).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I found an answer. It is by hearsay, untested.

Answer (score 1):

The difference that I had vaguely in mind and that made me ask what would make `ash` perhaps more comfortable was that in some containers, `sh` might not have auto-completion. This cannot be shown with the given example container.

Auto-completion means that you can write the start of something and press `<Tab>` to get it as the full name. For example when aiming at `cd MY_FOLDER`, `cd M`+`<Tab>` is enough, or when you open a file in another folder and you add the child paths step by step.

It is by hearsay, it is unknown in which container this ever happens. I could also be a trick that is just outdated, but then some old images should still be out there with the outdated version.

Comment: In your container image, `sh` also provides tab-completion: run `docker -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh python:3-alpine`, type `cd /m` then tab twice...

Comment: @StephenKitt I got the hint from someone. Thank you for testing, and you had already said that it might depend on the container - which is right then! I will accept your answer then. This answer is still what I was heading to: there are some (old?/outdated?/strange?) containers out there where you do have this auto-completion difference. The question was not asked for this detailed container, I added that later, and as I said, I had never seen the difference anyway. The message of this answer might still be right for some, as is yours. Yours seems more relevant today.

Comment: Yes, it’s a plausible difference; Bash at least behaves like that. The source code of the current version of Busybox indicates that Busybox `ash` doesn’t make this distinction nowadays, but perhaps it did in the past.